# Cakephp 3: Modifying Results from the database

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In my database there is a *content* table and when fetching data from this table I would like to append field *url* to the results, which is based on *slug* field which is contained in the table. Anyway, I have seen a way to do this in the previous versions of cakephp using behavior for the model of this table and then modifying results in afterFind callback in the behavior class. But in version 3 there is no afterFind callback, and they recommend using mapReduce() method instead in the manual, but this method is poorly explained in the manual and I cant figure out how to achieve this using mapReduce().

Comment: you can also create virtual property url  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little bit of research I realized that the best way to append the url field field to find results is using *formatResults* method, So this is what I did in my finders:

```
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results) {
               return $results->map(function ($row) {
                   $row['url'] = array(
                       'controller' => 'content',
                       'action' => 'view',
                       $row['slug'],
                       $row['content_type']['alias']
                   );
                   return $row;
               });
           });
```